# Render CMB2 select option to post page

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I'm using CMB2 plugin to add select metaboxes into a post. The metabox work fine on the post editor.
But failed to render and displaying on post page.

The code for post editor

```
    add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'postintro_metabox' );
    function myweb_postintro_metabox() {
    $myweb_grouppf = new_cmb2_box( array(
         'id'            => 'postintro_metabox',
         'title'         => __('Post Intro', 'MYWEB'),
         'object_types' => array( 'post', ), // Post type
         'context'       => 'normal',
         'priority'      => 'high',
         'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
    ) );  

    $myweb_grouppf->add_field( array(
        'name'             => 'Test Select',
        'desc'             => 'Select an option',
        'id'               => 'wiki_test_select',
        'type'             => 'select',
        'show_option_none' => true,
        'default'          => 'custom',
        'options'          => array(
            'standard' => __( 'Option One', 'cmb2' ),
            'custom'   => __( 'Option Two', 'cmb2' ),
            'none'     => __( 'Option Three', 'cmb2' ),
        ),
    ) );

    }
```

Then I try to call on my post with this code, but unfortunately did'nt work:

```
<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wiki_test_select', true ) ); ?>
```

Could you please help me out? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Questions regarding 3rd party plugins are considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here so you'lle need to dig into the plugins [documentation](https://cmb2.io/) or use its [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/cmb2/) to get an exact answer for you question.*

---

I would recommend you to `var_dump()` all of the post's meta to see, if the data is actually saved with the `wiki_test_select` key or has the plugin added some sort of prefix / suffix to it or used some other structure to store the data. If so, update your code accordingly.

```
// Using empty key returns all meta fields
var_dump( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '', true ) );
```